# migration from ActivityResult to Activity Result API

Tags: android, kotlin, onactivityresult

I'm new in programming, some technolgies i'm trying learn by myself, I've watched a lot of video new activity result Api, and i'm trying migrate in my project. everything fine , but trouble is the
missing request code, what have to do or use for request code .

here in project old Activity result trying to Crop Image

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) { /// неед
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_GALLERY) {
                data?.data.let {
                    if (it != null) {
                        imageUri = it
                        cropImage(it) }
                }

            } else if (requestCode == UCrop.REQUEST_CROP) {
                val resultUri = data?.let { UCrop.getOutput(it) }
                binding.image.loadUrl(resultUri.toString())
            }
        } else {
            toastMessage(requireContext(), getString(R.string.fail_download_image))
        }
    }

    private fun openGallery() {    /// галлерея
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_GALLERY)
    }
```

here I'm migrating Activirty Result Api

```
  val resultContract = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()){result: ActivityResult? ->
        if (result?.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_GALLERY) {
                result.data?.data.let {
                    if (it != null) {
                        imageUri = it
                        cropImage(it) }
                }

            } else if (result.requestCode == UCrop.REQUEST_CROP) {
                val resultUri = result.data?.let { UCrop.getOutput(it) }
                binding.image.loadUrl(resultUri.toString())
            }
        } else {
            toastMessage(requireContext(), getString(R.string.fail_download_image))
        }

    }
```

here in Activity Result Api request code is unresolved references , what to use instead of request code???

Comment: That's one of the ideas of result API, request code becomes internal implementation detail and you don't need to handle it anymore. Instead of checking for request code register separate contract for each type of request you're making.

Comment: @Pawel and if for example, I'm get in Gallery , i've choised one image,  before load image, i have to crop Image,  and finally  load this croped image .and make this operation only one time,  Then how Can launch this both contracts ??

Comment: If you have two separate callbacks for two separate launches, why aren't you calling `registerForActivityResult` twice?

Comment: @ianhanniballake  Ok, I'm called twice but, I've got one trouble for example is it working with image choising from Gallery  after cropping Image, and finally load image in Image view and everything should to be only by one click in Image

Comment: @ianhanniballake  i've called inside in intent anyway  working, but not dowloading Image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I'm late with the answer. If you really need to get the request code in Activity Result API you should do something like that:

```
// You can use any request code
val REQUEST_GALLERY = 1001
val resultContract = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()){result: ActivityResult? ->
val requestCode = result.data?.extras?.getInt(REQUEST_GALLERY.toString())

if (result?.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_GALLERY) {
            result.data?.data.let {
                if (it != null) {
                    imageUri = it
                    cropImage(it) }
            }

        } else if (result.requestCode == UCrop.REQUEST_CROP) {
            val resultUri = result.data?.let { UCrop.getOutput(it) }
            binding.image.loadUrl(resultUri.toString())
        }
    } else {
        toastMessage(requireContext(), getString(R.string.fail_download_image))
    }

}
```

Comment: Where are you getting "UPDATE_REQUEST_CODE"?

Comment: Basically it's enum and it can be any Long number. It works like any other request codes ))